# Getting error : An invalid API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of 2.0.0 in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure services in xamaring forms. When i use **useclient.SyncContext.PushAsync()** i get above error.

Does anyone know? Help me

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after upgrading Windows Azure package.